# Regular expression in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What should be the regular expression pattern for a tokenizer in Elasticsearch for matching C# and C++ each separately?

Right now we have one analyzer for this, but whenever we are trying to search C# it is showing C++ also as a match and vice versa.

Comment: What are you asking?  Do you want to analyse some C++ code?  or are you talking about the APIs to ES?

Comment: Not c++ code but i want to analyze special characters like +,# $ as tokens which is right now is not possible in standard analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, one thing you can do is set up an analyzer that just tokenizes on whitespace. The default [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) tokenizes on symbols as well as whitespace, so `"c++"` and `"c#"` both get turned into the term `"c"`, so both documents will match a search for one or the other.

One way around this (though it might cause you other headaches), is to use an analyzer like this:

```
"whitespace_analyzer": {
   "type": "custom",
   "tokenizer": "whitespace",
   "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding"
   ]
}
```

Or, in a full toy example, I can set up an index like:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

then add a few docs via the [`bulk api`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html):

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc", "_id":1}}
{"text_field": "some text with C++"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc", "_id":2}}
{"text_field": "some text with C#"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc", "_id":3}}
{"text_field": "some text with Objective-C"}
```

Now a search for `"C++"` only gives me back the document that contains that term:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "text_field": "C++"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.70273256,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.70273256,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "some text with C++"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and likewise with `"C#"`

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "text_field": "C#"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 0.70273256,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.70273256,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "some text with C#"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This solution may or may not end up giving you what you want, because it won't tokenize on punctuation either.

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/92871671ea7313356cbbd1ea900c3d55944bd20b

**EDIT:** Here is a slightly more advanced solution that can help solve the punctuation problem. I got the idea from [this article](http://www.fullscale.co/blog/2013/03/04/preserving_specific_characters_during_tokenizing_in_elasticsearch.html). The basic idea is that you can declare certain symbol characters to be alpha-numeric characters.

So I create the index using a custom [token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenfilters.html), then add the same three docs plus another one that the previous solution would not handle correctly:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "symbol_filter": {
               "type": "word_delimiter",
               "type_table": [
                  "# => ALPHANUM",
                  "+ => ALPHANUM",
                  "@ => ALPHANUM"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "symbol_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "text_field": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc", "_id":1}}
{"text_field": "some text with C++"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc", "_id":2}}
{"text_field": "some text with C#"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc", "_id":3}}
{"text_field": "some text with Objective-C"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc", "_id":4}}
{"text_field": "some text with Objective-C, C#, and C++."}
```

Now querying for `"C++"` will return both the documents that contain that token:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "text_field": "C++"
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.643841,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.643841,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "some text with C++"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.40240064,
            "_source": {
               "text_field": "some text with Objective-C, C#, and C++."
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code for this one:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/5c583b4e99b8f3b088925ccdb894695aa0c257cb